# Get multiple values from the same table based on a Join from a different table

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have a below requirement where i want to fetch a multiple values from a table using same table join multiple times. But I am not able to get the desired result.

Below is the query i have tried and its giving duplicate records and also lot of time to run on the entire set. I tried to use distinct but its lot of time  so i had to abort the query..

```
  SELECT 
HGHost.name AS HOST,
  HGDB.name        AS DATABASE,
  HGDB.dbms        AS DBMS,
  HGDB.server      AS INSTANCE,
  HGSCH.name       AS SCHEMA,
  HGTBL.name       AS "TABLE",
  HGCLM.name       AS "COLUMN",
  HGVAL.value    AS "HCDE",
  HGVAL1.value    AS "NOPI",
  HGVAL2.value    AS "Inf_CLAS"
FROM 
  XVIEW.XCATTR IGCCA INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL
  on IGCCA.RID=HGVAL.ofcustomattributeRID AND IGCCA.NAME = 'SURE_CLASS'
  INNER JOIN  XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL1 
  ON IGCCA.RID =HGVAL1.ofcustomattributeRID  AND IGCCA.NAME = 'NO_CLASS'
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL2
  ON  IGCCA.RID =HGVAL2.ofcustomattributeRID  AND IGCCA.NAME= 'Info_class'
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.DBCLM HGCLM
  ON HGVAL.OBJECTRID = HGCLM.RID
  OR HGVAL1.OBJECTRID = HGCLM.RID
  OR HGVAL2.OBJECTRID = HGCLM.RID
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASETABLE HGTBL
  ON HGCLM.ofdatabasetablerid = HGTBL.rid
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASESCHEMA HGSCH
  ON HGTBL.ofdataschemarid      = HGSCH.rid
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASE HGDB
  ON HGSCH.ofdatabaserid        = HGDB.rid
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRHOSTSYSTEM HGHost
  ON HGDB.hostedbyrid           = HGHost.rid
  WHERE HGHost.name = 'PROD'
  AND HGDB.name <> 'teradata'
```

Basically i want the values for HCDE, NOPI and Inf_clas from this XCATTRSTRVAL based on the join condition from XCATTR table.
Let me know if its clear.
Sample output: (the last 3 fields must be populated)

[image]

After running the Query, i am getting two rows as below. I want to combine them into one.
[image]

Comment: Add sample data with expected output.

Comment: What is the issue with the current query? It is giving no result or giving multiple records for the same record? edit the question and add the mentioned details.

Comment: yes, its giving duplicate records. Also, when i run on the entire set its taking lot of time. I think its doing a cross join.

Comment: Joining the same table twice `INNER JOIN  XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL1 
  ON IGCCA.RID =HGVAL1.ofcustomattributeRID  AND IGCCA.NAME = 'NO_CLASS'
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL2
  ON  IGCCA.RID =HGVAL2.ofcustomattributeRID  AND IGCCA.NAME= 'Info_class'` is causing the duplicates of records. What you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to get the values of NOPI, HCDE and INF_CLAS from the table XCATTRSTRVAL based on different join condition with XCATTR ( name column)

Comment: Oracle or Teradata? Those are two very different database products

Comment: Oracle as of now , but later i will run the same from TD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    HGHOST.NAME   AS HOST,
    HGDB.NAME     AS DATABASE,
    HGDB.DBMS     AS DBMS,
    HGDB.SERVER   AS INSTANCE,
    HGSCH.NAME    AS SCHEMA,
    HGTBL.NAME    AS "TABLE",
    HGCLM.NAME    AS "COLUMN",
    -- ADDED FOLLOWING AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN IGCCA.NAME = 'SURE_CLASS' THEN HGVAL.VALUE
    END) AS "HCDE",
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN IGCCA.NAME = 'NO_CLASS' THEN HGVAL.VALUE
    END) AS "NOPI",
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN IGCCA.NAME = 'Info_class' THEN HGVAL.VALUE
    END) AS "Inf_CLAS"
FROM
    XVIEW.XCATTR IGCCA
    INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL ON IGCCA.RID = HGVAL.OFCUSTOMATTRIBUTERID
                                           AND IGCCA.NAME IN (
        'SURE_CLASS',
        'NO_CLASS',
        'Info_class'
    )
    INNER JOIN XVIEW.DBCLM HGCLM ON ( HGVAL.OBJECTRID = HGCLM.RID )
    INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASETABLE HGTBL ON HGCLM.OFDATABASETABLERID = HGTBL.RID
    INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASESCHEMA HGSCH ON HGTBL.OFDATASCHEMARID = HGSCH.RID
    INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASE HGDB ON HGSCH.OFDATABASERID = HGDB.RID
    INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRHOSTSYSTEM HGHOST ON HGDB.HOSTEDBYRID = HGHOST.RID
WHERE
    HGHOST.NAME = 'PROD'
    AND HGDB.NAME <> 'teradata'
GROUP BY -- ADDED THIS GROUP BY
    HGHOST.NAME,
    HGDB.NAME,
    HGDB.DBMS,
    HGDB.SERVER,
    HGSCH.NAME,
    HGTBL.NAME,
    HGCLM.NAME;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: HGVAL1 and HGVAL2 Joins??

Comment: Not needed!! Try this and share if result is not as expected

Comment: But I am getting error :ORA-00904: "HGVAL2"."OBJECTRID": invalid identifier

Comment: Ohh!! Updated the answer.. please check now

Comment: Thanks for that. I need to combine the two rows into one (where the value is present) which i am getting after removing the group by.

Comment: Ok.. then you got your solution now?

Comment: Can you please share the actual and expected result?

Comment: Sorry, Its working fine. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think you accepted the different answer as correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just did.

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly need to join the table `XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL`, I guess you can write below query -

```
SELECT HGHost.name AS HOST,
       HGDB.name        AS DATABASE,
       HGDB.dbms        AS DBMS,
       HGDB.server      AS INSTANCE,
       HGSCH.name       AS SCHEMA,
       HGTBL.name       AS "TABLE",
       HGCLM.name       AS "COLUMN",
       MAX(HGVAL.value)    AS "HCDE",
       MAX(CASE WHEN IGCCA.NAME = 'NO_CLASS' THEN HGVAL.value END) AS "NOPI",
       MAX(CASE WHEN IGCCA.NAME = 'Info_class' THEN HGVAL.value END) AS "Inf_CLAS"
FROM XVIEW.XCATTR IGCCA
INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL ON IGCCA.RID= HGVAL.ofcustomattributeRID 
                                    AND IGCCA.NAME IN ('SURE_CLASS', 'NO_CLASS', 'Info_class')
INNER JOIN XVIEW.DBCLM HGCLM ON HGVAL.OBJECTRID = HGCLM.RID
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASETABLE HGTBL ON HGCLM.ofdatabasetablerid = HGTBL.rid
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASESCHEMA HGSCH ON HGTBL.ofdataschemarid = HGSCH.rid
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASE HGDB ON HGSCH.ofdatabaserid = HGDB.rid
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRHOSTSYSTEM HGHost ON HGDB.hostedbyrid = HGHost.rid
WHERE HGHost.name = 'PROD'
AND HGDB.name <> 'teradata'
GROUP BY HGHost.name,
         HGDB.name,
         HGDB.dbms,
         HGDB.server,
         HGSCH.name,
         HGTBL.name,
         HGCLM.name
```

Comment: HGVAL1 and HGVAL2 are not defined?

Comment: Thanks for that. I need to combine the two rows into one (where the value is present). See the updated results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to join to the same table multiple times?

Can you use the below? You might need to replace IIF with a CASE statement depending on your version:

```
SELECT 
HGHost.name AS HOST,
  HGDB.name        AS DATABASE,
  HGDB.dbms        AS DBMS,
  HGDB.server      AS INSTANCE,
  HGSCH.name       AS SCHEMA,
  HGTBL.name       AS "TABLE",
  HGCLM.name       AS "COLUMN",
  IIF(IGCCA.NAME = 'SURE_CLASS',HGVAL.value,NULL)    AS "HCDE",
  IIF(IGCCA.NAME = 'NO_CLASS', HGVAL.value,NULL)    AS "NOPI",
  IIF(IGCCA.NAME = 'Info_class', HGVAL.value,NULL)    AS "Inf_CLAS"
FROM 
  XVIEW.XCATTR IGCCA
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL   on IGCCA.RID= HGVAL.ofcustomattributeRID AND IGCCA.NAME = 'SURE_CLASS'
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.DBCLM HGCLM
  ON HGVAL.OBJECTRID = HGCLM.RID
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASETABLE HGTBL
  ON HGCLM.ofdatabasetablerid = HGTBL.rid
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASESCHEMA HGSCH
  ON HGTBL.ofdataschemarid      = HGSCH.rid
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASE HGDB
  ON HGSCH.ofdatabaserid        = HGDB.rid
  INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRHOSTSYSTEM HGHost
  ON HGDB.hostedbyrid           = HGHost.rid
  WHERE HGHost.name = 'PROD'
  AND HGDB.name <> 'teradata'
```

Comment: This wont work because the RID of the IGCCA is different for all the three IGCCA.NAME and that should match with ofcustomattributeRID of XCATTRSTRVAL to pick the value from XCATTRSTRVAL

Comment: Yes, so if you join IGCCA to XCATTRSTRVAL you'll get all of the IGCCA.NAME values. Did you try running this query?

Comment: Yes, i ran it changing to Case but getting error: But I am getting error :ORA-00904: "HGVAL2"."OBJECTRID": invalid identifier

Comment: Ok, try the above. I've made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMSes don't like `OR`ed join condtion, in Teradata it will always result in a (probably bad performing) *Product/Cross Join*. This is also the reason why you got too much rows, try rewriting as three joins instead:

```
SELECT 
  HGHost.name AS HOST,
  HGDB.name        AS DATABASE,
  HGDB.dbms        AS DBMS,
  HGDB.server      AS INSTANCE,
  HGSCH.name       AS SCHEMA,
  HGTBL.name       AS "TABLE",
  HGCLM.name       AS "COLUMN",
  HGVAL.value    AS "HCDE",
  HGVAL1.value    AS "NOPI",
  HGVAL2.value    AS "Inf_CLAS"
FROM 
  XVIEW.XCATTR IGCCA
INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL
  ON IGCCA.RID= HGVAL.ofcustomattributeRID
 AND IGCCA.NAME = 'SURE_CLASS'
INNER JOIN XVIEW.DBCLM HGCLM
  ON  HGVAL.OBJECTRID = HGCLM.RID
INNER JOIN  XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL1 
  ON IGCCA.RID=HGVAL1.ofcustomattributeRID
 AND IGCCA.NAME = 'NO_CLASS'
INNER JOIN XVIEW.DBCLM HGCLM1
  ON HGVAL1.OBJECTRID = HGCLM1.RID
INNER JOIN XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL HGVAL2
  ON IGCCA.RID=HGVAL2.ofcustomattributeRI
 AND IGCCA.NAME= 'Info_class'
INNER JOIN XVIEW.DBCLM HGCLM2
  ON HGVAL2.OBJECTRID = HGCLM2.RID
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASETABLE HGTBL
  ON HGCLM.ofdatabasetablerid = HGTBL.rid
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASESCHEMA HGSCH
  ON HGTBL.ofdataschemarid    = HGSCH.rid
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRDATABASE HGDB
  ON HGSCH.ofdatabaserid      = HGDB.rid
INNER JOIN XVIEW.PDRHOSTSYSTEM HGHost
  ON HGDB.hostedbyrid         = HGHost.rid
WHERE HGHost.name = 'PROD'
  AND HGDB.name <> 'teradata'
```

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth. I am not able to get any rows when I am running that. I am checking that once again

Comment: Try switching to `LEFT JOIN` for those joins to `XVIEW.DBCLM`

Comment: Still no result. I am able to get the result but i am getting two rows as updated in the requirement. I need just one row with all the values from two rows fro the last three columns.

Comment: Did you need additional modifications, like Left Joins to `XVIEW.XCATTRSTRVAL` or `Group By + Max`?